# why I cant call a PHP class and the function into it?

Tags: php

I have following php file structure

- ...index.php
- ... ...controllers (FOLDER)
- .....template.controllers.php
- ...
- ...views (FOLDER)
- .....template.php

index.php

```
<?php

$template= null;
require_once "controllers/template.controllers.php";
$template - new ControladorPlantilla();
$template -> ctrTraerPlantilla();

?>
```

template.controllers.php

```
<?php
Class ControladorPlantilla {
public function ctrTraerPlantilla(){

include "views/template.php";

}

}

?>
```

and I got the following errors

```
Notice: Object of class ControladorPlantilla could not be converted to int in index.php on line 14
FATAL ERROR: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function ctrTraerPlantilla() on null in index.php on line 15
Error: Call to a member function ctrTraerPlantilla() on null in index.php on line 15
```

Im just learning about PHP, thank for your help!

Comment: I think `$template - new ControladorPlantilla();` should be `$template = new ControladorPlantilla();` You dont have an equal sign

Comment: indeed, thank you! @altoids